# Cygwin install scipy error on compilation

Tags: scipy, cygwin

I am trying to install scipy under cygwin with pip, unfortunately I have some compilation errors! I attach log files. I have searched on web but have found nothing.

thanks

2023-02-11T17:48:15,190   [250/1620] Compiling C++ object scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.cpython-39-x86_64-cygwin.dll.p/_faddeeva.cxx.o

2023-02-11T17:48:15,191   FAILED: scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.cpython-39-x86_64-cygwin.dll.p/_faddeeva.cxx.o

2023-02-11T17:48:15,192   c++ -Iscipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.cpython-39-x86_64-cygwin.dll.p -Iscipy/special -I../../scipy/special -I/tmp/pip-build-env-m1hcjhav/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I../../scipy/_lib/boost -Iscipy/_lib -I../../scipy/_lib -I../../scipy/_build_utils/src -I/usr/include/python3.9 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -std=c++14 -O2 -Wno-cpp -MD -MQ scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.cpython-39-x86_64-cygwin.dll.p/_faddeeva.cxx.o -MF scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.cpython-39-x86_64-cygwin.dll.p/_faddeeva.cxx.o.d -o scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.cpython-39-x86_64-cygwin.dll.p/_faddeeva.cxx.o -c ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx

2023-02-11T17:48:15,193   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx: In function ‘npy_cdouble faddeeva_ndtr(npy_cdouble)’:

2023-02-11T17:48:15,194   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx:79:10: error: ‘M_SQRT1_2’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘NPY_SQRT1_2’?

2023-02-11T17:48:15,196      79 |     z *= M_SQRT1_2;

2023-02-11T17:48:15,199         |          ^~~~~~~~~

2023-02-11T17:48:15,200         |          NPY_SQRT1_2

2023-02-11T17:48:15,201   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx: In function ‘double faddeeva_log_ndtr(double)’:

2023-02-11T17:48:15,202   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx:108:18: error: ‘M_SQRT1_2’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘NPY_SQRT1_2’?

2023-02-11T17:48:15,203     108 |     double t = x*M_SQRT1_2;

2023-02-11T17:48:15,204         |                  ^~~~~~~~~

2023-02-11T17:48:15,205         |                  NPY_SQRT1_2

2023-02-11T17:48:15,206   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx: In function ‘npy_cdouble faddeeva_log_ndtr_complex(npy_cdouble)’:

2023-02-11T17:48:15,207   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx:130:53: error: ‘M_SQRT1_2’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘NPY_SQRT1_2’?

2023-02-11T17:48:15,208     130 |         complex<double> w = -0.5 * Faddeeva::erfc(z*M_SQRT1_2);

2023-02-11T17:48:15,209         |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~

2023-02-11T17:48:15,210         |                                                     NPY_SQRT1_2

2023-02-11T17:48:15,211   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx:136:11: error: ‘M_SQRT1_2’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘NPY_SQRT1_2’?

2023-02-11T17:48:15,212     136 |     z *= -M_SQRT1_2;

2023-02-11T17:48:15,218         |           ^~~~~~~~~

2023-02-11T17:48:15,219         |           NPY_SQRT1_2

2023-02-11T17:48:15,220   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx:146:34: error: ‘M_PI’ was not declared in this scope

2023-02-11T17:48:15,221     146 |     double im = fmod(mIm_z2, 2.0*M_PI);

2023-02-11T17:48:15,223         |                                  ^~~~

2023-02-11T17:48:15,224   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx: In function ‘double faddeeva_voigt_profile(double, double, double)’:

2023-02-11T17:48:15,225   ../../scipy/special/_faddeeva.cxx:177:24: error: ‘M_PI’ was not declared in this scope

2023-02-11T17:48:15,226     177 |         return gamma / M_PI / (x*x + gamma*gamma);

2023-02-11T17:48:15,227         |                        ^~~~

I expect to find a solution to this compilation problem! Since I cannot intervene in the code, I don't have much room for action.

Comment: Do you have the `python39-devel` package installed? The `python39-numpy` package? Other `scipy` dependencies? It may be that scipy has not been ported to cygwin. If that is the case, your best bet may be to subscribe to and post on the cygwin mailing list (See `https://www.cygwin.com/lists.html`.) The cygwin python package maintainer(s) follow and post on that list. That will be the best place to get help.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time on install scipy but now I managed!

My configuration on Cygwin : python 3.9.16 python3-devel 3.9.10.1

from github install OpenBLAS git clone https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git make; make install

then pip install scipy==1.9.3 (the last version 1.10.1 doesn't work! strange error: M_PI not definded in some step of cc compilation!?!?!)

and finally I installed Scipy!!!!

Another way (more clean): install python for windows, change PATH in .bashrc, put first the path /cygdrive/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311 in PATH variable)